# How to find damage per second using Average Damage, Accuracy and Fire Rate Per Second?

Tags: game-design, mathematics, statistics

I was wondering if anyone could help me establish a DPS equation using the variables 'Average Damage', 'Accuracy (%)', and 'Fire Rate Per Second'.

Here is my table:

[image]

Note: These numbers are examples only!

Comment: What gives you the problem, what have you tried?

Comment: Just multiply the three values.

Comment: Too trivial to belong on the site. Also, a general programming question.

Comment: I need to find a DPS using three variables at my own digression, i'm terrible at math so forgive my ignorance. I thought that this might work: Average Damage x Accuracy / FRPS

Comment: This is basic, you should really learn maths.

Comment: -1. This could probably be found out with basic "example problems". A damage per second of something with 2 average damage, 100% accuracy, and 1 fire rate per second would be 2 dps. That makes it pretty obvious that "average damage * (accuracy% / 100) * fire rate" = dps. As Alexandre Vaillancourt said, you should definitely learn more math(s), it's very important in programming and you're gonna want to know a lot of it.

Comment: Also - a key to what type of question belongs here: will a game developer give you a different answer than say a mathematician, a physicist, or just a regular programmer? If not then it doesn't really belong, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not this way? Much easier?

damagePerSecond = averageDamage * fireRatePerSecond * accuracy

Example:

damagePerSecond = 140 * 10 * 0.09

Comment: This implies that the values for the accuracy be stored as ratios instead of percentages.

Comment: Ratios and percentage are almost the same, the equation would become `damagePerSecond = averageDamage * fireRatePerSecond * accuracy/100` with accuracy in %

Answer (score 0):

DPS = (total / rate) * accuracy;

so for shotgun:

```
damagePerShot = 140;
totalPerSec = damagePerShot * 10;
dps = (totalPerSec / 100) * 9;
```

so I figure average dps of 126 for a shotgun.
Sound Good?